# What is "[Xamarin.Forms.ContentProperty("Contents")]" above a class actually doing?

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I understand how this code works but can someone explain what the first line does?  Is this translated some place into some C# code.  How about if I wanted to code this manually, how could I go about that?

```
[Xamarin.Forms.ContentProperty("Contents")]
class PopupFrame : Frame
{
    StackLayout contentStack { get; } = new StackLayout();

    public IList<View> Contents { get => contentStack.Children; }


    public PopupFrame()
    {
        Content = contentStack;

        HasShadow = true;
        HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.FillAndExpand;
        Padding = 0;
        VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.Center;
    }
}
```

Comment: In C#, something in square brackets in front of a language element (in this case, in front of a class declaration) is known as an attribute. An attribute is actually an instance of an attribute class (in this case, the `ContentPropertyAttribute` class). It nearly always acts to add *metadata* to the assembly containing the thing being attributed. The properties of that class instance are included in the metadata. Look up the `ContentPropertyAttribute` class docs to get more info

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This attribute tells the XAML processor that if should use the `Frame`'s `Content` property as the default basically. So, in practice it allows you to write this

```xml
<ContentView>
    <Label Text="Hello, Forms"/>
</ContentView>
```

Instead of

```xml
<ContentView>
    <ContentView.Content>
       <Label Text="Hello, Forms"/>
    </ContentView.Content>
</ContentView>
```

Examples taken from the [Docs page](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/xamarin.forms.contentpropertyattribute?view=xamarin-forms).

In regard to your question "how do I write this in C#?" you don't. This is something specific to XAML and nothing more than syntactic sugar. In C# you would simply assign something to the `Content` property. I.e.:

```cs
var frame = new Frame();

Frame.Content = new Label() { Text = "Hello, Forms" };
```